# Vertically align label and select text to the left

Tags: html, css

I have a simple native `label` and `select` elements stacked. But as you can see in the snippet, the label text is not vertically aligned to the select's text on the left side like this

[image]

```css
select { 
 display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    border: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22292.4%22%20height%3D%22292.4%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23007CB2%22%20d%3D%22M287%2069.4a17.6%2017.6%200%200%200-13-5.4H18.4c-5%200-9.3%201.8-12.9%205.4A17.6%2017.6%200%200%200%200%2082.2c0%205%201.8%209.3%205.4%2012.9l128%20127.9c3.6%203.6%207.8%205.4%2012.8%205.4s9.2-1.8%2012.8-5.4L287%2095c3.5-3.5%205.4-7.8%205.4-12.8%200-5-1.9-9.2-5.5-12.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"),
      linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%
      );
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
    background-position: right 0.7em top 50%, 0 0;
    background-size: 0.65em auto, 100%;
    }
```

```html
<label>Label</label>
<select class="select-css">
                <option>How to left align this text with label?</option>
                <option>Apples</option>
                <option>Bananas</option>
                <option>Grapes</option>
                <option>Oranges</option>
              </select>
```

EDIT:
I have currently forced it by using like `margin-left: -3px` on the `select` element...

Comment: can you explain the question a little more clearly, what do you need?

Comment: Sorry my bad. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

Typically this would involve floats but with modern CSS3 you can use Flexbox. Wrap the label and select in a container and use `display: flex` on it. The default flex item behaviour will give you the desired alignment.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
 <div class="flex-container">
  <label>Label</label>
  <select>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: There are so many more alignment properties as well, take a look at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox -- this will be useful once your layout becomes more complicated.

Comment: I clarified what I meant by vertically aligned to the left side..

Comment: There is still nothing wrong with using floats in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.contaienr {
  display: flex;
}

select {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22292.4%22%20height%3D%22292.4%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23007CB2%22%20d%3D%22M287%2069.4a17.6%2017.6%200%200%200-13-5.4H18.4c-5%200-9.3%201.8-12.9%205.4A17.6%2017.6%200%200%200%200%2082.2c0%205%201.8%209.3%205.4%2012.9l128%20127.9c3.6%203.6%207.8%205.4%2012.8%205.4s9.2-1.8%2012.8-5.4L287%2095c3.5-3.5%205.4-7.8%205.4-12.8%200-5-1.9-9.2-5.5-12.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E"), linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  background-position: right 0.7em top 50%, 0 0;
  background-size: 0.65em auto, 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="contaienr">
  <label>Label</label>
  <select class="select-css">
    <option>How to left align this text with label?</option>
    <option>Apples</option>
    <option>Bananas</option>
    <option>Grapes</option>
    <option>Oranges</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I clarified what I meant by vertically aligned to the left side..